# Unit Testing Input Event in Angular6

Tags: angular

I have an Input field in the UI

`<input matInput placeholder="BLC" id='blc' formControlName="blc" (change)="onBLCChanged($event)" />`

I want to do unit testing for this, but this field send $event not any value to the function, how can I mock this.

```
  it('some text', async(async() => {
    spyOn(component, 'onBLCChanged');
    // first round of change detection
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // get ahold of the input
    let input = debugElement.query(By.css('#blc'));
    let inputElement = input.nativeElement;

    //set input value
    inputElement.value = 'test';
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

    expect(component.onBLCChanged).toHaveBeenCalledWith({});
  }));
```

This is not working, `Expected spy onBLCChanged to have been called with [ Object({  }) ] but actual calls were [ [object Event] ].`

Please help, `onBLCChanged` is the method in the .ts file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```js
it('some text', async(async() => {
      spyOn(component, 'onBLCChanged');
      // first round of change detection
      fixture.detectChanges();
      // get ahold of the input
      let input = debugElement.query(By.css('#blc'));
      let inputElement = input.nativeElement;

      //set input value
      inputElement.value = 'test';

      // save event object so that you can do comparison.
      const event = new Event('change');
      inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);

      expect(component.onBLCChanged).toHaveBeenCalledWith(event);
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 it('some text', async(async() => {
    const spyOnFunction = spyOn(component, 'onBLCChanged');
    // first round of change detection
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // get ahold of the input
    let input = debugElement.query(By.css('#blc'));
    let inputElement = input.nativeElement;

    //set input value
    inputElement.value = 'test';
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

    expect(spyOnFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```